# Memory issue when create a diagonal numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory

I have created a diagonal numpy array:

```
a = numpy.float32(numpy.random.rand(10))
a = numpy.diagonal(a)
```

However, I face `MemoryError` since my matrix is extremely large. Is there anyway to save the memory?

Comment: Depending on the size of the array, you'll need to use sparse matrices, see [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//scipy/reference/sparse.html). Memory is an [intrinsic problem](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/04/28/how-much-ram-do-i-need-to-store-that-matrix.html) of large arrays.

Comment: numpy is for arrays of the same type which allows efficient memory usage and element access, As @t.o. says a sparse matrix may well be the way to go if that suits your need. You could simulate a simple matrix to store diagonal elements using a dictionary with keys of tuple `(x, y)` and this is very memory efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this case is to create a sparse matrix using `scipy.sparse.diags` as follows:

```
a = numpy.float32(numpy.random.rand(10))
a = sparse.diags(a)
```

If the shape of your diagonal numpy array is n*n, utilizing sparse.diags would result in a matrix n times smaller. Almost all matrix operations are supported for sparse matrices.